# Access MySQL server on Windows from Vagrant

Tags: database, windows, database-connection, vagrant

I've been trying to connect to my database with no success. From XAMPP or HeidiSQL I can connect to my database (Oracle MySQL Server 5.5) using IP 127.0.0.1 or just localhost, but I can't figure out how can I connect to this DB from Vagrant. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So with some help I managed to connect. All I had to do, was to connect to Vagrant IP ending on 1 (my vagrant IP is 172.17.2.3 so I had to connect to 172.17.2.1) and also had to create another DB user without IP restriction.